# How do I fix the "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I am attempting to create a doubly linked list and use a function which accepts a value passed by reference. However, when I try to access the value it throws an error. I am getting the "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment &da= NULL;"

I have tried:

```
 #ifndef __DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H__
 #define __DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H__
 //
 //
 #include
 #include
 using namespace std;

 class DoublyLinkedList {
 public:
 DoublyLinkedList();
 ~DoublyLinkedList();
 void append (const string& s);
 void insertBefore (const string& s);
 void insertAfter (const string& s);
 void remove (const string& s);
 bool empty();
 void begin();
 void end();
 bool next();
 bool prev();
 bool find(const string& s);
 const std::string& getData() const;

 private:
 class Node
 {
 public:
 Node();
 Node(const string& data);
 ~Node();
 Node* next;
 Node* prev;
 string* data;
 };
 Node* head;
 Node* tail;
 Node* current;
 };

 DoublyLinkedList::Node::Node(const string& da)
 {
 this->data=nullptr;
 this->next=nullptr;
 this->prev=nullptr;
 &da= NULL;
 }
```

Comment: Unrelated: Believe it or not, `__DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H__` is an illegal identifier. Any identifier with two underscores in a row anywhere in it is reserved. More details: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: should I change it to one underscore? that part of the code was given by my instructor

Comment: Preceding underscore at global scope is illegal, so `_DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
&da= NULL;
```

is trying to set NULL to the address of the variable `da`. You can't do that.

You might mean

```
this->data = &da;
```

which would `work` (as in, compile), but would probably cause errors if the string passed as `data` goes out of scope before your list does (which is very likely).

What you probably actually want, if you're going to use a `string*`, is

```
this->data = new string(da);
```

which dynamically allocates a new string, giving it `da` to copy from. In the destructor, you'd then want something like

```
if (data != nullptr) delete data;
```

I'm not a Standards guy, so can't give you the technical explanation of `lvalues` and such.